# Java+Maven builds on Jenkins but not on local machine

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a strange problem. My build is working on Jenkins but not locally. It used to work locally but stopped for some reason.

I have no uncommitted changes. The code on Jenkins is in sync with my master branch(using Git).

I have deleted all uncommitted files from my local machines project.

Mvn -version on local machine:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T09:58:13+02:00)
Maven home: /Users/andersvincentlund/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 9.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_SE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Tool configuration on Jenkins machine:

```
jdk-9.0.1
apache-maven-3.5.2
```

Compiler plugin in Maven in the code:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Build result on Jenkins:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] RootProject ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.781 s]
[INFO] ProjectA ........................................ SUCCESS [ 15.344 s]
[INFO] ProjectB ............................................ SUCCESS [ 35.063 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Build result from local machine:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] RootProject ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.350 s]
[INFO] ProjectA ........................................ SUCCESS [  1.285 s]
[INFO] ProjectB ............................................ FAILURE [  1.402 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Failures in ProjectB are referencing packages in Project A. All look like this:

```
[ERROR] /somePath1/src/main/java/somePath2/SomeFile.java:[10,38] error: package some.package.in.projectA does not exist
```

I know my Maven and Java aren't exactly the same version on the different machines. The local one is a Mac running Sierra. The remote one is Windows Server 2012 R2. Since I am using the maven compile plugin to set the version to Java 7 it shouldn't be a problem right? I don't get this. Normally the issue is that it is working locally but not on Jenkins. This is the other way around. Help would be greatly appreciated. Starting to feel really stupid over here.

EDIT:
Tried on another Mac. Same result as with my Mac, failure. Created a VM with Windows and tried again, same result as with the server. Success. Seems to be a problem isolated to Mac. It has worked on Mac before so I am considering if an update has broken something.

Comment: Are you building with the same JDK version ?

Comment: jdk-9.0.4.jdk and jdk-9.0.1

Should that cause problems in accessing packages?

Comment: I would suggest if you are working with JDK 9 to upgrade maven-compiler-plugin 3.7.0 ...furthermore what looks strange is the big different in build time between local/jenkins? A full log out put would be helpful...

Comment: I updated the plugin with no help, but that's a good thing to do either way. Yes the build time is quite extreme on my computer, but the server with jenkins is crazy fast and my machine is old. The log is really just several occurances of that. The only thing I am omitting is the quantity of rows of the same structure. Can't really give away the package names because I'd be breaking an NDA.

Comment: Ok that's good which removed the potential problem with an older version of the plugins...Furthermore are you really running on Jenkins with JDK 9 ? Correctly configured to run a freestyle job or do you use a Maven Job or Pipeline job in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I a compile action works on Windows but not on OSX/Linux the most common failure is a file with wrong uppercase or lowercase character in the file name (or directory name).

As Windows works case insensitive it is able to find and access the file.

OSX and Linux are working case sensitive and therefore are not able to acces the file.

Check the directory names of the package `some.package.in.projectA`
and the filename of the Java files that they exactly match the package respectively class name(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Checked that and all package names are lower-case. Same for directories. The only things that are uppercase are the *.java files and the directories before /src/etc.

Comment: @why_vincent And does the class and the package name declared match the file/directory names?

Comment: Yep. Checked with the 'tree' command in unix and compared to how the packages are defined/referred in the files.

Comment: package name was correct but somehow the "java" folder had disappeared under main. Should have spotted it. Since it was before the package I didn't check but I'll give you correct answer because you led me to start checking that further.